# Como por link em table?

Tags: php, html, table, link

Eu tenho um ***Table*** em **PHP** e em cada **tr** preciso de um link

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "saber");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select id,nome,vista from mensagens");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width = '86%'>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
    if($row['vista'] == 1)
        echo "<td>Sim</td>";
    else
        echo "<td>Não</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Alguém sabe como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que isso resolve no caso de trs:

```
echo '<tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href=\''.$link.'\'">';
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode inserir o link dentro da `<td>`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><a href=".$row['link'];
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td width = '86%'>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
if($row['vista'] == 1)
    echo "<td>Sim</td>";
else
    echo "<td>Não</td>";
echo "</tr></a>";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Para fazer com que em cada tr tenha um link você poderá utilizar javascript:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr onclick='location.href=.$row['link']."\'";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td width = '86%'>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
if($row['vista'] == 1)
    echo "<td>Sim</td>";
else
    echo "<td>Não</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Olá Ricardo eu enganei  quando disse que era todos os td, era todos os tr, ou seja quando se clica numa row vai para outro link

Comment: @BrunoGibellino Editei, teste ai.

Comment: Não funcionou no tr porém funcionou num td que eu testei.Mas não consigo fazer com que o link funcione no tr

Comment: de me mais informações será colocado somente um link ou sera colocado um link em cada row (tr)?

Comment: em cada tr vai ter um link

Comment: @BrunoGibellino Editei.

Answer (score 1):

O link não pode ficar por fora da Td. tem que ficar dentro da td. Envolvendo somente o texto.

```
echo "<td><a href='".$link."'>" . $row['id'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: Boas Lucas eu enganei-me ao elaborar a pergunta eu quis dizer em todos os tr's

Answer (score 0):

Terás de colocar um href a rodear a `<td>`

```
echo "<a href=\"link\"><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td></a>";
```

Comment: O a href precisa estar dentro da td, não fora, ou seu HTML ficará inválido

Comment: nuussssaa.......